# Where is the MySite user details stored - SharePoint 2010 (My settings)

Tags: 2010, my-site, ups

I have a user who needs to change is name when he opens up mysite and then "my Settings" - the URL is https://XXX/MySite/_layouts/userdisp.aspx

I have checked the user profile and it all seems ok there but not in mySettings.

Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check his profile at UPS configuration at central administration

Comment: I stated in my original post that in UPS its correct

Answer (score 0):

you can try with creating a new user profile property and Name it with Full    Name or so and mark the property as user overridable , then the user can edit  the property. As name property in User Profile is default property and is by  default it is non overridable.

Comment: Thanks Sunil where and how can the user edit it.can u share the url please?

Comment: Have configured mysite for the webapplication?